# Where can I get the template used for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, design

Where do I get a web template for a Q&A site like Stack Overflow? The look of the site is now common across many Q&A sites and they should release the template for mass use.

It's similarly used on [Super User](http://superuser.com) and [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), and they fit the style and fit of Stack Overflow.

I would love to use the same layout on a project of mine.

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: There is a big difference between homage and plagiarism.

Answer (score 3):

It's not freely distributed, but you can sign up for an account at [www.stackexchange.com](http://www.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This refers to Stack Exchange 1.0, and is no longer true.